# Template file not created after adding Page Class to models.py

Tags: wagtail

So I'm trying to get started with Wagtail, following the [10 minute guide](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html?_ga=1.205675731.1573091662.1484846284) but I'm having a problem creating [A basic blog](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html?_ga=1.205675731.1573091662.1484846284#a-basic-blog).

So after modifying `blog/models.py`:

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel

class BlogIndexPage(Page):
intro = RichTextField(blank=True)

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('intro', classname="full")
]
```

And running `makemigrations` and `migrate`:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations

Migrations for 'blog':
  blog/migrations/0001_initial.py:
    - Create model BlogIndexPage

$ python manage.py migrate

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, home,     sessions, taggit, wagtailadmin, wagtailcore, wagtaildocs, wagtailembeds,      wagtailforms, wagtailimages, wagtailredirects, wagtailsearch, wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  Applying blog.0001_initial... OK
```

The default template (blog/templates/blog/blog_index_page.html) is nowhere to be found. From what I understand, this file should be created automatically:

> Since the model is called BlogIndexPage, the default template name (unless we override it) will be blog/templates/blog/blog_index_page.html:

Or perhaps I'm missing something?

> Wagtail uses normal Django templates to render each page type. It automatically generates a template filename from the model name by separating capital letters with underscores (e.g. HomePage becomes home_page.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour. The template file / directory isn't created automatically on creating the page model - you have to add it yourself.

Comment: Alright, guess this statement left me a bit confused. "Wagtail uses normal Django templates to render each page type. It automatically generates a template filename from the model name by separating capital letters with underscores (e.g. HomePage becomes home_page.html)"

Comment: Aha - yes, I can see how the phrase "automatically generates a template filename" could be misleading. (It would be better to say something like "automatically determines the filename to be used".) We'll fix that - thanks very much for the feedback!